# Problemas com conexão externa SQL Server no PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, servidor, conexão

estou com um problema a dias com uma conexão externa PDO sqlsrv, já varri a internet e não encontrei uma solução.

Instalei todos os drivers do sql server para o PHP, inclusive, instalei o sql server na minha maquina para testa uma conexão local e funcionou... porém, a conexão externa não funciona no PHP. Eu consigo conectar normalmente no servidor externo pelo Management Studio de SQL, colocando IP, usuário e senha.

Aqui é o código e o erro:

```
try
{

    $servidor = "aqui vai o ip";
    $instancia = "instancia";
    $porta = 1433;
    $database = "banco";
    $usuario = "usuairo";
    $senha = "senha";

    $conexao = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server={$servidor}\\{$instancia},{$porta};Database={$database}", $usuario, $senha );
}
catch ( PDOException $e )
{
    echo "Drivers disponiveis: " . implode( ",", PDO::getAvailableDrivers() );
    echo "<br> Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Erro:

```
Drivers disponiveis: mysql,odbc,sqlite,sqlsrv
 Erro: SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Falha de logon do usuário 'usuairo'.
```

Alguém ajuda??

Comment: Criaste o usario para a base de dados no teu server?

Comment: @Pbras , sim, usuário e senha, funciona no Management Studio, mas não no PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta: `new PDO("sqlsrv:server={$server};Database={$database}" $user, $pass);`

Comment: Obg, já tinha resolvido, sua resposta é igual ao exemplo na minha pergunta, com a diferença da instancia. O Erro ocorreu porque um funcionário que cuidava do servidor tinha bloqueado esse usuário.

Comment: é que na sua pergunta ta uma "\\" e troquei por ";"